# Cron in AWS Elastic Beanstalk to fire js file

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to fire js file every minute in CRON within AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. The file is never however fired.

Here's my cron config for EB. I placed it in `.ebextensions` and named it `cron-linux.config`:

```
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

  "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash

      date > /tmp/date     // inside here I can see actual date so cron works 

      node ./var/app/current/scripts/testCrobJob.js     //this file is not fired

      exit 0

commands:
  remove_old_cron:
    command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Ran a modified version of this code to just create a file.

**File:** `./.ebextensions/cron-linux.config`

```sh
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

  "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash

      date > /tmp/date     // inside here I can see actual date so cron works 

      node /tmp/test.txt     // <----- THIS WAS CREATED

      exit 0

commands:
  remove_old_cron:
    command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

You might need to remove the extra dot a the beginning, because that's setting the directory to a relative path for `./var` vs the root `/var` path.

If you can SSH into the machine and run that code manually within it, you should be able to see the error.

**Potential Solution:**

```sh
      node /var/app/current/scripts/testCrobJob.js
```

Comment: @murakami Let me know if this is the answer so we can mark it correct. If not, let me know so I can try and debug it on my end.